# How does one define weak convergence of probability measures in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, optimal-transportation

I am reading the following [article](http://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/346/champion-depascale.pdf) and on page 9/17 (above Eqn (4.9)) the authors state that if $\gamma_{\epsilon_k}|\_G_{\delta}\times \Omega\to \gamma|\_G_{\delta}\times \Omega$ as $\epsilon_k\to 0$ in the weak* limit then $P^{t}_{\#}\gamma_{\epsilon_k}|\_G_{\delta}\times \Omega$ converges weakly in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ to $P^{t}_{\#}\gamma|\_G_{\delta}\times \Omega,$ where

- $\Omega$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d,$
- $G_{\delta}$ is some borel subset of $\Omega,$
- $\gamma, \gamma_{\epsilon_k}\in \mathcal{P}(\Omega \times \Omega)$ with first marginal $\pi^{1}_{\#} \gamma_{\epsilon_k} =\pi^{1}_{\#} \gamma =\mu << \mathcal{L}^{d}$ and,
- $P^{t}(x,y)=(1-t)x+ ty$ for $t\in [0,1]$ and for all $x,y\in \Omega.$

I am not sure how one defines convergence in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ of the push-forward measure $P^{t}_{\#}\gamma_{\epsilon_k}|\_G_{\delta}\times \Omega.$ Reading the paper so far I am guessing that for any borel set $B\subset \Omega$ and $\mu\in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ we define the $L^{\infty}$ norm of the measure as,
$$\mu(B)\leq ||\mu||_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} \mathcal{L}^{d}(B),$$
but I am not sure. Any references will be much appreciated.

Comment: That paper is poorly written. I suspect that the various measures are absolutely continuous  and the various densities are $L^\infty$. The reference [29] is about absolute continuity.

Comment: Does anyone know what $\lfloor$ (rendered by the OP as $|\_$) means?

Comment: Oh sorry I was trying to write the restriction of the measure to a certain set

Comment: What do you mean by "the restriction of the measure to a certain set"?